# Обязан ли <fstream> включать хедер <ios> (напрямую или косвенно)?

Tags: c++

Надо ли включать хедер `<ios>` для `std::ios_base`, если уже включен хедер `<fstream>`?

Для хедера `<iostream>` в доках [явно прописано](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream), что `<ios>` включается. А для `<fstream>` -- [нет](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream).

Comment: Надо, причем даже если он включен в fstream. Стоит делать файлы самодостаточными, чтобы они не поломались, если вдруг кто-то прекратит использовать fstream и уберет соотв. заголовочный файл из инклюдов.

Comment: Включает. Но не на прямую.

Comment: @user7860670 под "включает" в вопросе понимаю включение по стандарту, а не то, что конкретная реализация может включать, а может не включать. Включение `<fstream>` может не включить `<ios>`, так? Вот тут вроде говорят, что обязан включать https://stackoverflow.com/q/45624450

Comment: @user7860670 про самодостаточность работает в обратную сторону в моём случае: используется `std::ios_base::app` вместе с `std::ifstream` только, поэтому если оставить два включения, то при желании удаление одного не удалит второй, а надо бы. Но это лучше, конечно, чем НЕ включить и сломаться на какой-то реализации

Comment: Хотя может и напрямую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Надо ли включать хедер `<ios>` для `std::ios_base`, если уже включен хедер `<fstream>`?

Не обязательно. `std::fstream` (точнее его шаблонная версия) является потомком `std::ios_base`, поэтому by-design любой файл, в котором будет определение `std::fstream`, должен (вероятно, опосредованно) включать и определение `std::ios_base`, хотя будет ли это именно файл с именем `<ios>`, вообще говоря, не гарантируется.